# Подсчитать варианты паролей из строго 8 символов

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

**Сколько вариантов паролей, который состоит строго из 8 символов (не больше и не меньше) может быть?**

1. Пароль состоит может состоять только из 28 символов латиницы в нижнем регистре
2. Символы в пароле не повторяются

*Если можно на каком-нибудь ЯП, с выводом этих вариантов.
Спасибо большое за вашу доброту.*

Comment: [Размещение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: Помогите на каком-нибудь ЯП это реализовать, пожалуйста @Igor

Comment: мозгов не хватает, хелп @wololo :( не могу вывести варианты на экран...

Comment: @Igor там же через факториал нужно, ибо символы не повторяются

Answer (score 3):

Вам правильно указал @wololo

> В комбинаторике [размеще́нием](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (из n по k) называется упорядоченный
> набор из k различных элементов из некоторого множества различных n
> элементов.

A_28^8 в вашем случае.

```
28*27*26*25*24*23*22*21=125318793600
```

Comment: @xpaco добавил ответ для наглядности

Comment: Весьма благодарен Вам, земляк.Подскажите что означает "А_",

Comment: Количество размещений из n по k, обозначаемое {\displaystyle A_{n}^{k}}A_{n}^{k}

Comment: По ссылке если пройти то можно увидеть

Comment: Благодарю Вас, пусть Ваши руки никогда не устают! Вы вдохновили меня, теперь буду учить мат. часть:)

Comment: Зачем учить в этом нет необходимости. Нужно просто знать и понимать как и где искать. Вы же не учите таблицу умножения до сотен только до десяти.

Comment: Тоже верно :) пока мои комментарии модераторы не стали удалось, пожалуйста расскажите о себе, очень интересно чем вы занимаетесь или кем работаете и в каком Государстве. Интересно узнать, где находятся наши умы:)

Comment: а по какой ссылке нужно перейти, чтобы увидеть, как Вы сказали?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123429/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-xpaco).

Comment: :( не достает репутации в англоязычном аккаунте, чтобы писать в чате...

Comment: Ясно а посмотреть можно там на линкед скинул ссылку